# Flourish: How to select one-to-many

Tags: php, mysql, flourishlib

Let's suppose there is a set of A and for each a of A there is a set of B. In short:
A:B = 1:n

Let's suppose, there is an a, which is an A and it is interesting. However, I would like to select a with all its B elements.

For instance, let's consider the example of Companies and Workers. For the sake of simplicity, we assume that a Worker works at a single Company and a Company might have a natural number of Workers.

If I want to select a set, containing the values of Company.Name, Worker.Name of a given Company, then what should I do in PHP, to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, assuming you have this schema

Table Company

- CompanyID (PK)
- CompanyName
- other columns..

Table Worker

- WorkerID (PK)
- WorkerName
- CompanyID (FK)

You can join the tables by linking `Company` and `Worker` with `CompanyID`

```
SELECT  a.Name CompanyName,
        b.Name WorkerName
FROM    Company a
        INNER JOIN Worker b
            ON a.CompanyID = b.CompanyID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you, but the reason I am using an ORM is that I want to avoid writing SQLs. Is there a way in Flourish to achieve a join without writing SQL queries?